# what is the use of int i()

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define main() main(){printf("hi");}int i()
main()
{//empty main
}
```

what is the use of `int i()`

Comment: Your code makes no sense. I edited it but I pretty much just put everything four spaces to the right. As it stands, `int i();` is a prototype for a function `i` which returns an `int` and takes no arguments.

Comment: @aaron It does build, it just turns into two functions `main() {printf("hi");}` and `int i() {}`, but that macro is fairly nonsensical. It's some sort of evil witchcraft to replace `main`, and I would very much hate to ever come across that in real code

Comment: @Michael, I never said it didn't build ;)  I did miss the braces making it a definition and not a prototype though.

Comment: You should be telling us what is the use of i

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty silly program, but the purpose of the `int i()` is so that it will compile - the braces at the end:

```
{//empty main
}
```

will cause an error if there isn't a function declaration included in the `#define` statement.  If I delete it, gcc gives the error:

```
testfile.c:4: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
```

You can use the `-E` flag to gcc to see why the `int i()` is necessary - it will show you the output of the preprocessor without compiling.

Answer (score 3):

Think about what you get if you expand the macro `main()` in the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){printf("hi");}int i()
{//empty main
}
```

The `int i()` is needed there to make the remaining `{ ... }` part of a syntactically valid function definition.

As for intention, I can only guess that the point of the macro is to replace the existing `main` with a stub one.  It's a bit icky IMO.

Answer (score 3):

In that code `main()` will be expanded and the result will end with

```
int i()
{//empty main
}
```

> what is the use of `int i()`

It makes the output of a very strange and broken macro compilable